# Java HttpServlet Body "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request" POST

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest

Problem: I get "Bad Request" when trying to replicate my *working* Postman example...

I have my Java HttpServlet setup to send a POST-Request.

I can do the request in *Postman* no problem:

[image]

...but in my Java-Environment I get the "Bad Request 400" error ->

```
//CONFIGURE CONNECTION
proxyConnection.setRequestMethod(method);
proxyConnection.setDoInput(true);
proxyConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        
JsonObject parent = new JsonObject();
parent.addProperty("client_id", "clientXXY");
parent.addProperty("client_secret", "jxx.2221122");
parent.addProperty("username", "API.PRODTEST");
parent.addProperty("password", "kkGGkkGGEEee1");
        
OutputStream os = proxyConnection.getOutputStream();
os.write(parent.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
os.close();

//ESTABLISH CONNECTION
proxyConnection.connect();
```

[image]

```
// ----> this throws "Bad Request"
System.out.println("ret mess " + proxyConnection.getResponseMessage() );
```

Comment: They aren't the same and thus fail. You are sending a form from postman and json from your java part. Those are totally different things and thus it fails.

Comment: I appreciate your input and would appreciate any kind of point-me-in-the-right-direction help / example / link or anything

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to post an answer to my problem for anyone doing the same thing the wrong way.

Yes, instead of JSON I needed to send the data as String parameter, see following code --->

(Special thanks to *M. Deinum* for pointing it out)

```
//CONFIGURE CONNECTION
proxyConnection.setRequestMethod(method);
proxyConnection.setDoInput(true);
proxyConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        
// JsonObject parent = new JsonObject();
// parent.addProperty("client_id", "clientXXY");
// parent.addProperty("client_secret", "jxx.2221122");
// parent.addProperty("username", "API.PRODTEST");
// parent.addProperty("password", "kkGGkkGGEEee1");
        
// OutputStream os = proxyConnection.getOutputStream();
// os.write(parent.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
// os.close();


        String proxyQuery = "client_id=x&client_secret=x&grant_type=password&username=API.x&password=x&acr_values=";

        byte[] postData = proxyQuery.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
        int postDataLength = postData.length;
         
        proxyConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        proxyConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength ));
        proxyConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        try(DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(proxyConnection.getOutputStream())) {
           wr.write( postData );
        }


//ESTABLISH CONNECTION
proxyConnection.connect();
```